# Hardware issues with 2 series condensers with heat pump in heat mode

Tags: discussion

I am planning to use a second heat exchanger to added inline to remove heat from a standard mini split heat pump system. The refrigerant will flow from the compressor to an added water coil exchanger, then on to the expected wall unit.

I am interested in constructive reasons why this could cause premature hardware failure, or otherwise wouldn't work. Specifically, if all the refrigerant was condensed in the first exchanger and only a liquid flowed to the second air exchanger in the wall unit.

Some background:
This type of configuration is already used, it's called a desuperheater. It is often used to produce domestic hot water, as it can be as hot as the superheated refrigerant leaving the compressor. What I think is unique about my situation is that I would like to pull a majority of the heat out, so much that there may be only small amounts of gas refrigerant left, or maybe none (all converted to liquid by releasing heat).

I wonder if there is any issue with colder than expected refrigerant returning to the compressor.

My goal is to store energy via warming water (when there is excess capacity in the system = warm outside in the day), for use in radiant heat during times when the heat pump is less efficient (night time cold outside).

My plan includes some automation that will adjust the flow of water through the exchanger, as well as manipulate the temperature setpoint of the indoor air handler to achieve the desired total heat flow (aka mass flow, compressor speed).

For example, if only 30% of a systems capacity is being used, increase the output to 80% and extract 50% via water temperature increase for use later.

The documentation for the mini split lists that it will diagnose an error (no refrigerant) if it sees no refrigerant temperature drop across the air handlers exchanger for a sustained period of time. It is my assessment that as long as there is some temperature drop it cannot know the other exchanger is using the majority of the heat.

[image: Log log plot of Enthalpy and Pressure with isotherm lines for the refrigeration cycle]

Comment: The professional solution involves a manifold which, I believe, runs the heads in parallel rather than series.

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off with a heat-pump chiller and chilled/heated water heads.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because custom thermal system engineering is beyond the scope of Home Improvement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on DIY meta are supposed to be questions about the main DIY site. This is not the place for off-topic discussions about other things.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like a better question for https://sustainability.stackexchange.com - a better fit for the high theory often discussed there, and frankly, the forum could use the traffic.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the comments! This was my first question asked so my apologies for putting it in the wrong location.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I need to copy paste this question into the sustainability area, and delete this question, right?

Answer (score -2):

Your plan is not DIYable because of international regulations on who may service heat pumps.  As such, it's going to get an "approval pass" by the professional who you retain for this work.

Making all of this work will be part of the engineering you will need to build the system. This will require consultation with the heat pump manufacturer.

Not least, you will need to find a way to not turn your water heater into a water chiller during A/C season LOL.  This is one reason a series arrangement is probably not appropriate.  Also thermal control of the water - that MUST be managed safely.

Rather than try to invent something that is *novel* and *problematic*, I would simply stick with gold-standard methods for doing that thing.  There are plenty of heat pumps which support multiple indoor heads.  One of them can be a water heater.  This would be a "parallel" solution rather than the serial solution you imagine, but it would workable and supported.

Lastly, consider the thermal storage capacity of water.  Most HVAC equipment uses "BTU" when they mean "BTU/hour".  An actual BTU is the energy needed to heat 1 pound of water 1 degree F.   Think about how much water you need in your storage tank.  A modest furnace might be 50,000 BTU/hour, or 15kW if we use an electric unit like a general energy unit.  What is 50,000 BTU in water?  Assuming you run 100 degrees rise on the water (which is pretty ambitious), that's 500 pounds of water (60 gallons).  Also equivalent to 15 kWH of energy storage.  So if your 50,000 BTU furnace (a small one) is running 33% duty cycle, that 60 gallons will last you 3 hours.

But water's not the only place you can store heat.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI